# Spring security: filter engaged to client credentials oauth2 token exchange

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using `RestTemplate` in order to comunicate with other services. My project is using Spring Boot 2.4.4. `WebClient` is not available.

My Spring security related dependencies are:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.4.4:compile
  27   │ [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.5:compile
  28   │ [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.5:compile
  29   │ [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.4.5:compile
  30   │ [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.4.5:compile
  31   │ [INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.5:compile
  32   │ [INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.5:compile
  33   │ [INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.4.5:compile
  34   │ [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.4.5:compile
  35   │ [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:5.4.5:compile
```

I'm using `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.4.5` in order to get token.

Currently, I'm using a custom filter in order to handle token exchange and insert requested token into `Authorization` header.

My `JWTHeaderRequestInterceptor` class is:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JWTHeaderRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    private final AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;

    /**
     * Injects current jwt on {@link HttpHeaders#AUTHORIZATION} header.
     */
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
            HttpRequest request,
            byte[] body,
            ClientHttpRequestExecution execution
    ) throws IOException {
        request
            .getHeaders()
            .set(
                HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,
                SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX.concat(this.getToken())
            );

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }

  public String getToken() {
    OAuth2AuthorizeRequest oAuth2AuthorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("espaidoc")
      .principal("scheduler")
      .build();

    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorize = this.authorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.authorize(oAuth2AuthorizeRequest);
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorize.getAccessToken();

    return accessToken.getTokenValue();
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using `AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` in order to get accessToken.

My Spring Security Oauth2 Client related configuration is:

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceAndManager (
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
      OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
        .clientCredentials()
        .build();

    AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
    new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
      clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);

    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
  }

}
```

Spring security Oauth2 client properties:

```java
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.espaidoc.client-id=RDOCSCHEDULER
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.espaidoc.client-secret=ic12Unv2UI5EXFNjbrv8RVHPgUQV0T8D
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.espaidoc.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.espaidoc.scope=internal
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.espaidoc.client-name=espaidoc scheduler OAuth2 Client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.espaidoc.provider=espaidoc-oauth2-provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.espaidoc-oauth2-provider.authorization-uri=http://keycloak-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es/realms/master
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.espaidoc-oauth2-provider.token-uri=http://keycloak-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.espaidoc-oauth2-provider.user-info-uri=http://keycloak-espaidoc-transversal.apps.ocpdes.t-systems.es/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

```java
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(
        RestTemplateBuilder builder,
        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager
    ) throws Exception {
        return builder
                .additionalInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new JWTHeaderRequestInterceptor(authorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager)))
                .build();
    }
```

I'm tried to look for an already predefined filter inside `spring-security` is engaged to handle it.

Any ideas?

Remember that I'm using `spring-security 5.4.5`.